# Fill formula down to same level in adjacent column does not work when combined with other working code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, webvtt

I am creating lots of training material and need to transcribe video/audio files to add closed captions. Getting a new software approved takes forever where I work, so I looked at what I had. MS Office.

I ultimately need to create a .vtt file to upload into Articulate360 (create txt file UTF-8 and change the extn).
The vtt file needs a specific format with a specific word at the top then a clear line, timestamp (in a certain format), the text on the next line, clear line - repeat timestamp/text/clear line.
Here starts my intro to VBA. I can make it work, but I can't make all the working bits work together.

An example working vtt file is below for format:

```
            WEBVTT
                    
             00:00:01.100 -->   00:00:06.000
             Saving a query is very simple. Navigate to the query icon. 
             
             00:00:06.100 -->   00:00:12.000
             Then find your query you wish to save. Click on the disc icon. 
             
             00:00:12.100 -->   00:00:16.000
             Add a name.    
             
             00:00:16.100 -->   00:00:19.000
             Then click save.   
             
             00:00:19.100 -->   00:00:22.000
             And that is your query saved.  
             
             00:00:22.100 -->   00:00:27.000
             If we show the queries again, you can now see my saved query.
```

As I am new to Macros I did it in steps and edited from recording my actions/using forums. I have tried lots so this is long.
I use Word to transcribe and then I add to document with timestamps.
It has the following format with some word formatting:

```
              Audio file
              transcribed file name as a link
              Transcript
              00:00:01
              Saving a query is very simple. Navigate to the query icon.
              00:00:06
              Then find your query you wish to save. Click on the disc icon.
              00:00:12
              Add a name.
              00:00:16
              Then click save.
              00:00:19
              And that is your query saved.
              00:00:22
              If we show the queries again, you can now see my saved query.
```

I have the following working macros but I am having trouble combining them.
This Macro works and runs from Word to remove formatting add the milliseconds portion, arrow and blank lines

```
             Sub CCCWordStep1()
             '
             CCCWordStep1 Macro
             Prep file for excel
             ' "&chr(10)&"1:Remove Link
             ' "&chr(10)&"2:Clear all formatting
             ' "&chr(10)&"3:Append '.100 -->' to the timestamp
             ' "&chr(10)&"4: Add required blank lines
             
             
             '
             Selection.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Delete
             Selection.ClearFormatting
             Selection.WholeStory
             Selection.ClearFormatting
             Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
             Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
             With Selection.Find
                     .Text = "^#^#:^#^#:^#^#"
                     .Replacement.Text = "^p^&.100-->"
                     .Forward = True
                     .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                     .Format = False
                     .MatchCase = False
                     .MatchWholeWord = False
                     .MatchWildcards = False
                     .MatchSoundsLike = False
                     .MatchAllWordForms = False
             End With
             Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
             
             
             End Sub
```

Then I have another macro to copy, paste as text in excel, save as xlsx file (I couldn't get it to save as a readable text file so removed that requirement for now), close/quit

```
            Sub CopyWordDocToExcel()
              Dim wdApp As Object
              Dim wdDoc As Object
              Dim xlApp As Object
              Dim xlWb As Object
              Dim xlWs As Object
              
                  'Get the running instance of Word and the active document
              Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
              Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
              
                  'Create a new instance of Excel and add a new workbook
              Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
              Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
              
                  'Copy the contents of the Word document to the clipboard
              wdDoc.Content.Copy
              
                  'Paste the contents into the first worksheet of the new Excel workbook
              Set xlWs = xlWb.Worksheets(1)
              xlWs.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
              
              
                  'Save and close the Excel workbook
              xlWb.SaveAs "C:\VBA\Workbook.xlsx"
              xlWb.Close
              
                  'Quit Excel and release objects from memory
              xlApp.Quit
              Set xlWs = Nothing
              Set xlWb = Nothing
              Set xlApp = Nothing
              
              End Sub
```

I have a macro in Excel that does the other edits I require:

```
            Sub excel1()
              Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
              Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
              Range("A1").Select
              ActiveCell.Value = "WEBVTT -" & ActiveCell.Value
              Range("B3").Select
              ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(RC[-1],""*-->""),(CONCAT((LEFT(R[3]C[-1], LEN(R[3]C[-1])-7)),""000"")),""""),""01:00:00.000"")"
              Dim lastRow As Long
              lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
              Range("B3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B3:B" & lastRow)
              End Sub
```

This gives me my excel file in the required format which I then open, manually save as a .prn file (txt file gave some other issues and this way works) and manually change the extn in file explorer, upload to Articulate and it works.

However, if I try to run the code below from Word, I get a file saved, I get the removed rows, the edited A1 cell is only the original value (no WEBVTT - added) and no formula or autofill.(FYI: If I paste the working excel code directly as written above I get no edits at all)

```
            Sub CopyWordDocToExcelEdited()
              Dim wdApp As Object
              Dim wdDoc As Object
              Dim xlApp As Object
              Dim xlWb As Object
              Dim xlWs As Object
              
                  'Get the running instance of Word and the active document
              Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
              Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
              
                  'Create a new instance of Excel and add a new workbook
              Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
              Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
              Set xlWs = xlWb.Worksheets(1)
              
                  'Copy the contents of the Word document to the clipboard
              wdDoc.Content.Copy
              
                  'Paste the contents into the first worksheet of the new Excel workbook
              
              xlWs.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
              
                  'make an edit
              
              xlWs.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
              xlWs.Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
              xlWs.Range("A1").Select
              ActiveCell.Value = "WEBVTT -" & ActiveCell.Value
              xlWs.Range("B3").Select
              ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIF(RC[-1],""*-->""),(CONCAT((LEFT(R[3]C[-1], LEN(R[3]C[-1])-7)),""000"")),""""),""01:00:00.000"")"
              Dim lastRow As Long
              lastRow = xlWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
              xlWs.Range("B3").AutoFill Destination:=xlWs.Range("B3:B" & lastRow)
              
              
                  'Save and close the Excel workbook
              xlWb.SaveAs "C:\VBA\Workbook.xlsx"
              xlWb.Close
              
                  'Quit Excel and release objects from memory
              xlApp.Quit
              Set xlWs = Nothing
              Set xlWb = Nothing
              Set xlApp = Nothing
              
              End Sub
```

I have these references checked:

[image: references]

Answer (score 1):

The error is 'cos you use  "" -  replace symbol **"** in formula body to `&Chr(34)&`  and all will work

Comment: I have taken this advice but it still is not running. I am going through each section of the edit. I may be back with the other errors tomorrow